# ajax internal server error with large data set

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script that updates a database that is almost working.  Because of some items outside of my control, I could not use a Put to do an update/insert.  The process that I have to use is somewhat like this.

`addRecords` function, takes each line of the object and go a Get on 3 data elements, if there is a match pass the record id along with the rest of the data to a Put ajax function, if there is no match pass the data to a Post ajax function.

Currently if the data file is large enough, then the ajax Get function does give a 500 (Internal Server Error).  This seems to be only happening at the rate of <1 record per 1000.

I think that I am just overloading the server.  I would like to find some way to "throttle back" the ajax calls so that the server does not get overloaded.

I have tried to edit to put an if statement that would look to see how many have been sent vs. how many have been completed, but have not had any success. What would be the best way to limit how much data is currently in the addRecords function?

The add records function:

```js
function addRecords(lines) {
    lines.forEach(function(v) {
        $j.ajax(
            "/ws/schema/table/U_STATEADM",
            {
                "type": "GET",
                "data": 'q=student_key==' + v.STUDENT_KEY + ';schoolid==' +
                        v.SCHOOLID + ';report_period==' + v.REPORT_PERIOD +
                        '&projection=id',
                "indexValue": v,
                "datatype": "text",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "error": function(data) {
                    // alert("There was an error!");
                },
                "success": function(data) {

                    if (data.record.length == "1") {
                        //update record
                        //gives record id
                        var newid = data.record[0].id
                        //gives reply from GET statement
                        //gives information for what was submitted on GET
                        //works, takes id from GET and information sent to get and updates database
                        {
                            $j.ajax(
                                "/ws/schema/table/U_STATEADM/" + newid,
                                {
                                    "type": "PUT",
                                    "data": JSON.stringify({
                                        "id": newid,
                                        "name": "U_STATEADM",
                                        "tables": {
                                            "U_STATEADM": v
                                        }
                                    }),
                                    "headers": {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        };
                    } else if (data.record.length == "0") {
                        alert("No Record Found");
                        //insert record using post
                        //works to insert new lines
                        {
                            $j.ajax(
                                "/ws/schema/table/U_STATEADM",
                                {
                                    "type": "POST",
                                    data: JSON.stringify({
                                        "tables": {
                                            "u_stateadm": v
                                        }
                                    }),
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    "headers": {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                },
                "complete": function() {
                    completed++;
                    // console.log(completed, "End Completed");
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

And part of the function that creates the object and sends it to the addRecords function:

```
for (var i = 4; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    //Add key to array
    var newkey = data[0] + data[4] + data[5];
    // data.splice(0,0,newkey);

    //remove unused data elements
    data.splice(1, 3);
    data.splice(3, 1);
    if (data.length == headers.length) {
        lt++;
        var tarr = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            tarr[headers[j]] = data[j];
        }
        lines.push(tarr);
    }
}

//try to get back id from data
//loop through all lines in file
//This version does give objects of success linked from information sent on
// get to information returned on get, from

 addRecords(lines);
```

Comment: Check the server for error. Debug on server and see if theres any error in code for large data set first then you could filter it down to server load.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Sorry that i am just now replying, i have been out of the office in some meetings.  The only thing that I can find in the log is an entry of Exception thrown in REST endpoint.  Java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: debug and check the values of objects if populating correctly or not. It will be easier to find.

Comment: I have tried looking on the server for more information.  It is somewhat difficult to find any information.  I am trying to write the code using html and JavaScript for a student information system package.  We are given the ability to create custom pages and have just now been given the REST api access.  There is a limit on what information that I have access to, however, i did hear from others that sending too much at one time causes errors.  Like juggling too many balls causes random balls to drop.  If i can keep the number of "balls" to under 500 at a time the risk of dropping is low.

Comment: I have heard of others putting if statements inside of while loops, however those were for just a POST statement.  Some of the confusion comes from this statement having a GET that then depending on finding or not branches off to a PUT or POST before the complete.  The other part of the confusion is that I am trying to code far beyond my ability.  Again thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have REST which will respond to PUT and POST on array of input?

Comment: I do have a rest for PUT and POST.

Comment: I was finally able to get that working by taking the parts of the code and making them their own function.  I then called that function and returned values to get the code to run in blocks.  Ran into other problems with the data that I have to use, but that is another problem.